# ignore case in for loop when property does not exist

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am making a `GET` request to an endpoint.

This returns an array containing many objects, some of which contain a url for a photo.

If the individual object contains a photo I want to display it, if not just ignore.

I expected the following code to work, and ignore the cases where the photo does not exist, but I am still getting the following error message.

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined(…)

```
$.get(url, function (data) {
    for(var i = 0; i < data.length; i++){
        if(data[i].media[0].img){
            console.log(data[i].media[0].img);          
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: please share the `data` object

Comment: Please first console.log(data); and show the object after code . Then i can help you .

Comment: @JasonP apologies, it is working, just changed some of the extra code to make it easier to read for the purpose of the question.

Comment: answer below works

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$.get(url, function (data) {
  for(var i = 0; i < data; i++){
    if(data[i].media && data[i].media[0]){
        console.log(data[i].media[0].img);          
    }
   }
});
```

Comment: It will check if there is media element and inside there is element so when you want img property it will get. 
If you dont have media element if you want to access "img" property the error is thrown.

Comment: data[i].media evaluates as truthy or falsy depending on if it is null or not when placed in a conditional. The assumption being you are getting this error because media is null and you are trying to grab an index from it.

Comment: @user2693928 this will work! i will mark as answer when it allows me